# Can I use a whole widget/screen as modal bottom sheet?

Tags: flutter

I have a login screen, which I want to be accessible at different points throughout the app. Can I use that screen as a modal bottom sheet like this?

[example from airbnb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP6YF.png)

Comment: Yes why not ? Please describe solution/code that you implemented and please don't ask suggestion related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, the below code snippet is used to show bottomsheet:-

```
bottomSheetForSignIn(BuildContext context)
{
  showModalBottomSheet(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(25),topRight: Radius.circular(25)),
      ),
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (context){
        return SignIn();
      }
  );
}
```

and then create a stateful widget signin returning a container with a property height(to control like in how much part of screen you want to show bottom sheet)

Code for it will look like:-

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.9,//to control height of bottom sheet
      child: Column( //your design from here onwards
        children: [
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And whenever you want to open bottom sheet just make a call to:-

```
bottomSheetForSignIn(context);
```